# MSBuild deployment to machine outside of company network

Tags: deployment, tfs, msbuild, msdeploy, msbuildextensionpack

Is it possible to deploy code (asp.net mvc application and Windows Service) to machine in public hosting (for example VM on Godaddy) using TFS MSBuild from internal network (company network)

All than I have is IP address of destination server, username and password. But I am not sure than TFS can deploy code at such machine. 
When I doing it on local server, normally I specify path like this:
\machine-name\c$\deployment-folder\
But it is not working with remote machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of tfs are you using? There are community extensions to MSbuild and / or TFS 2010 team build activities that allow you to call ftp, ssh, scp or any number of tools to move files about. It's more dependant on what mechanisms the 3rd party offers for deployment. For example if go daddy support FTP, then you can either invoke the windows FTP command or use the numerous extensions.

Comment: TFS 2012 (tfspreview.com) - but I also need some control over services, for example, MSBuild should stop windows service, deploy a new version and start windows service again.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like InstallShield or Windows Installer XML to develop a Windows Installer database (.msi).   Use TFS Team Build to build the MSI.  Then use [PsExec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) to copy the MSI to the remote machine and execute it.